# Using if else statement for multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

Sample data:

```
x<-runif(100, min=0, max=1)
y<-runif(100, min=0, max=1)
dif<-x-y
dat<-data.frame(x,dif)
```

What I want to do is to create another column in data frame `dat` called `suit`. If `x` is less than 0.15 and `dif` is less than 0, than `suit` should have a value of 3. If `x` is less than 0.15 and `dif` is greater than 0, than `suit` should have a value of 2 and if `dif` is greater than 0, than `suit` has value of 1.

This is the code that I am prepared.

```
if(dat$x<0.15 & dat$dif<0){
   dat$suit<-3
} else {
if(dat$x>=0.15 & dat$dif<0){
   dat$suit<-2  
} else {
  dat$suit<-1  
 }
}
```

It gives all the values of `dat$suit` as 1. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done using either `ifelse`

```
with(dat, ifelse(x < 0.15 & dif <0, 3, ifelse(x > 0.15 & dif < 0, 2, 1)))
```

Or

```
with(dat, as.numeric(factor(1+4*(x < 0.15 & dif < 0) + 2*(x>=0.15 & dif < 0))))
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your statement is that `if` only checks the first element of the expression tested -- you should have received a warning.  `ifelse` is vectorized.

In addition, you can perform the tests in the reverse order for a simpler, equivalent expression:

```
with(dat,
     ifelse(dif >= 0 , 1 , ifelse(x < 0.15, 3, 2))
)
```