# if and if-else statements with multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, rstudio

I restarting my learning of R and working on understanding the basics before jumping into a project.  I am following a few courses ran by Udemy.  I am a little confused about an error I am receiving when running a multi condition `if` statement.

```
    student.df <- data.frame( name = c("Sue", "Eva", "Henry", "Jan"),
                      sex = c("f", "f", "m", "m"), 
                      years = c(21, 31, 29, 19)); student.df

    student.df$male.teen = ifelse(student.df$sex == "m" & student.df$years < 20,
    "T", "F"); student.df

    student.df$male.teen = if (student.df$sex == "f" & student.df$years < 20) {
      "T" 
    } else {
      "F"
    }
```

`In if (student.df$sex == "f" & student.df$years < 20) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

From what I understand is that I cannot have more than one condition with an `if` statement.  Though with a `ifelse` statement, I can have as many as I want?  If this is true, why do `if` statements only allow one condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using if else statement for multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812623/using-if-else-statement-for-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Yes, the second answer to the post you provided does answer my question "`if` statement checks first condition and `elseif` checks vector conditions (multiple)".