# Create a new column based on true/false conditions of other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I manually this dataframe but I want to know what code I could write to generate the 'name' column with the conditions being:

if 'dog' is TRUE and 'blackfur' and 'whitefur' are FALSE, then name equals 'no_dog'.

if 'dog' is TRUE and 'blackfur' is TRUE and 'whitefur' is FALSE, then name equals 'black_dog'.

if 'dog' is TRUE and 'blackfur' is FALSE and 'whitefur' is TRUE, then name equals 'white_dog'

```
ID  dog     blackfur    whitefur    name
1   TRUE    FALSE       FALSE       no_dog
2   TRUE    TRUE        FALSE       black_dog
3   TRUE    TRUE        FALSE       black_dog
4   TRUE    FALSE       TRUE        white_dog
5   TRUE    FALSE       TRUE        white_dog
6   TRUE    FALSE       TRUE        white_dog
7   TRUE    FALSE       FALSE       no_dog
8   TRUE    TRUE        FALSE       black_dog
9   TRUE    FALSE       TRUE        white_dog
```

Comment: Welome to Stackoverflow. It would be easiest if you `dput` your tibble above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using if else statement for multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812623/using-if-else-statement-for-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 2):

`case_when` is the function you are looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.csv(text = "ID,dog,blackfur,whitefur
1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
2,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
4,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
5,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
6,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
7,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
8,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
9,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE")

df %>%
mutate(name = case_when(dog & blackfur == FALSE & whitefur == FALSE ~ 'no_dog',
                        dog & blackfur & whitefur == FALSE ~ 'black_dog',
                        dog & blackfur == FALSE & whitefur ~ 'white_dog'))
```

The `case_when` function has a pretty decent vignette that describes the function better than I could: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `data.table` you can do the following:-

```
dt[, sum := 1 * dt$dog + 2 * dt$blackfur + 3 * dt$whitefur]
dt[, name := ifelse(sum == 1, "no_dog", ifelse(sum == 3, "black_dog", 
             ifelse(sum == 4, "white_dog", "")))]
dt[, sum := NULL]
```

If you have a `data.frame`, then you can do the following:-

```
dt$sum <- 1 * dt$dog + 2 * dt$blackfur + 3 * dt$whitefur
dt$name <-  ifelse(dt$sum == 1, "no_dog", ifelse(dt$sum == 3, "black_dog", ifelse(dt$sum == 4, "white_dog", "")))
dt["sum"] <- NULL
```

Edit: Math

Basically you multiply the second column by 1, the third column by 2 and the fourth column by 3, you can get different results depending on which columns have `TRUE` and which have `FALSE` values in them.

This is because we don't want same value when different columns have `TRUE` or `FALSE` values. For example, if `dog == TRUE` and `blackfur == TRUE` but `whitefur == FALSE`, our sum will be `2`. But we can also have a sum of `2` if `dog == TRUE` and `whitefur == TRUE` but `blackfur == FALSE`. Since, we need to differentiate between these two scenarios, we the second column by 1, the third column by 2 and the fourth column by 3.

If we did this , then with `dog` and `blackfur` equal to `TRUE`, we would get `1*1 + 2*1 = 3`, and with `dog` and `whitefur` equal to `TRUE`, we would get `1*1 + 3*1 = 4`, hence, a different answer.

This will give us three unique values:-

```
Condition                  Value
dog == TRUE -                1
dog & blackfur == TRUE       3
dog & whitefur == TRUE       4
```

And according to these values we can chain the `ifelse` to get different values of the `name` column. If the `sum == 1`, then we get `no_dog`. Else, if the `sum == 3`, then we get `black_dog`. Else, if the `sum == 4`, then we get `black_dog`.

Comment: Mention might be made, by way of explaining to a newly arrived OP, of the relationship of 1 & 0 to TRUE and FALSE behind the math, as well the chaining of ifelse.

Answer (score 0):

This only meets the first condition.

```
dat1 = data.frame(dog = TRUE, blackfur = FALSE, whitefur = FALSE)

 library(tidyverse)
    dat1 = dat1 %>% mutate(name = if(dog == TRUE){
      if(blackfur == FALSE){
        if( whitefur == FALSE){
          name = "nod_dog"
        }
      }
      
    })
```

Comment: A few suggestions: You don't need to load all the tidyverse packages since you're only using dplyr. For testing conditional operations like this, it's really going to be important that you're testing a representative set of conditions, not just a single row. If it only works on one condition, it's not all that useful. You're also using `if` / `else` for what should be a vectorized operation. Also you misspelled "no_dog"

Answer (score 0):

This uses logical operators directly on the relevant columns.

```
df <- read.csv(text = "ID,dog,blackfur,whitefur,name
1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,no_dog
2,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,black_dog
3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,black_dog
4,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,white_dog
5,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,white_dog
6,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,white_dog
7,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,no_dog
8,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,black_dog
9,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,white_dog")

df$name <- ifelse(
        df$dog & !df$blackfur & !df$whitefur,
        "no_dog",
        ifelse(df$blackfur, "black_dog", "white_dog")
)
```